# Run a cURL command in a browser

Tags: http, curl, post, get

How do I run a cURL command like this

`curl -X GET http://www.in.com/`
I am using windows 8.

How do I run this inside a browser say using NETWORK tab/or any other tab
I know that there is an option in Network tab to copy as curl command ,but I want to execute it right over there in firefox not in cmd /terminal.

What do i do to modify that command and execute it in the network tab over there only.

Yes , I am not asking for places like http://onlinecurl.com/ which allow you to execute curl commands online
Is it possible?
I have tried FIrebug in firefox but it according to my research does not have this option.
If yes please tell me how.

Answer (score -6):

Why not just put the URL in the address field for the browser?  The browser is going to do a "GET" request on this URL and return the results.  This is what curl is doing.  If you are trying to do a "PUT" or a "POST" request, then you would need to do something different, but for "GET", it should just work.